# Database > Table Prefix > WordPress Missing

Tags: php, wordpress, config

I really need help. I have developed my WordPress website, then I thought of strengthening the security. so, I changed my database table prefix, database user, and password into strong random character, and then afterwards, WordPress went missing. It went back to the installation.

I tried updating my wp-config.php

```
define( 'DB_USER',
define( 'DB_PASSWORD
$table_prefix =
```

but it has gotten even worse. Now the WordPress is totally gone. I just don't know what to do. I am hoping that it will be back because I still have the database, but I just don't know how, or where I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Open your wp-config.php file which is located in your WordPress root
> directory. Change the table prefix line from wp_ to something else
> like this wp_a123456_

```
**$table_prefix  = 'wp_a123456_';**
```

> That’s why to make things faster, we have a SQL query that you can use

```
RENAME table `wp_commentmeta` TO `wp_a123456_commentmeta`;
RENAME table `wp_comments` TO `wp_a123456_comments`;
RENAME table `wp_links` TO `wp_a123456_links`;
RENAME table `wp_options` TO `wp_a123456_options`;
RENAME table `wp_postmeta` TO `wp_a123456_postmeta`;
RENAME table `wp_posts` TO `wp_a123456_posts`;
RENAME table `wp_terms` TO `wp_a123456_terms`;
RENAME table `wp_termmeta` TO `wp_a123456_termmeta`;
RENAME table `wp_term_relationships` TO `wp_a123456_term_relationships`;
RENAME table `wp_term_taxonomy` TO `wp_a123456_term_taxonomy`;
RENAME table `wp_usermeta` TO `wp_a123456_usermeta`;
RENAME table `wp_users` TO `wp_a123456_users`;
```

**next step:**

> We need to search the options table for any other fields that is using
> wp_ as a prefix, so we can replace them. To ease up the process, use
> this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_a123456_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%wp_%'
```